# Shorten the touch delay in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch, delay, ios

I'm looking to shorten the touch delay on a UIScrollView, but I don't want to use setDelaysContentTouches:NO; I still want there to be a slight delay but my users are complaining about it being too long.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The doc says

> If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer
>   elapses, the scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and
>   performs the scrolling itself. Subclasses can override the
>   touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:, pagingEnabled, and
>   touchesShouldCancelInContentView: methods (which are called by the
>   scroll view) to affect how the scroll view handles scrolling gestures.

So i think there is no easy way to do it. You probably have to reimplement the whole timer system in those methods.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem and this is my solution:

Subclass UIScrolView

Add override these methods:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{


    self.lastTimestamp = [NSDate date];

    return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
}

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
      NSDate *now = [NSDate date];


     if (-[self.lastTimestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:now] < _delay)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```