# UIScrollView get contentOffset without delay?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I need to get x offset from UIScrollView when user drags it or system animates its scrolling.

I am using `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` to get offset value of Scroll view, but it appears to be delivered with a slight delay, without respect to acceleration of drag gesture.

Is it possible to get actual offset value without delay?

upd: As I see from profiler it is not performance issue by no means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080520/shorten-the-touch-delay-in-a-uiscrollview

Comment: thanks for pointing that question, looks quite disappointing

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck "Delays content touches" property of the scroll view in IB.

Comment: Unfortunately that not helped, `delaysContentTouches` is about determining whether "touch" or "drag" occurs, my situation is different